# Run my app on a PC for end user

Tags: android, virtual-machine, exe

I have an apk file, I want to package it with virtual box to be an exe file to run on any pc easily, I prepared Android 4.2 image and installed my apk on it and make on app start automatically after boot by code like this

```
public class MyActivityRunOnStartup extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }

}
```

My problem is How to package virtual box app (without installation) with android image that includes my apk

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood the question properly, but isn't the Android Studio and Android SDK Tools what you are looking for?

It has an Eclipse-based programming IDE, and virtual machines with Android images that do exactly what your are asking for.